How to access environment variables with Cloudflare Pages/Workers?
Using Vue I'm trying to access some environment variables that contain sensitive data using process.env.ENV_VAR and it works locally but it doesn't work with Cloudflare Pages, after reading their docs it seems I have to use fetch to access the env vars (https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/configuration/environment-variables/) but I don't quite understand how should I access the env vars, what I ended up doing is create a env_data.js file that should export the env vars, the file contains are:
let TURNSTILE_SITE_KEY;
let TURNSTILE_SECRET_KEY;

function fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    TURNSTILE_SITE_KEY = env.TURNSTILE_SITE_KEY;
    TURNSTILE_SECRET_KEY = env.TURNSTILE_SECRET_KEY;
}

fetch()

export default {
    TURNSTILE_SITE_KEY,
    TURNSTILE_SECRET_KEY
}

I import it with import env_data from "@/env_data.js"; and try to access the data with env_data.TURNSTILE_SITE_KEY but it doesn't work as Cloudflare errors when building the functions:
 Error: Failed to publish your Function. Got error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TURNSTILE_SITE_KEY')
  at functionsWorker-0.5745917335237649.js:5:28 in fetch2
  at functionsWorker-0.5745917335237649.js:8:1

How should I access the environment variables?
I want to clarify, besides trying to access the environment variables in a function (/functions/api/funct.js) I'm also trying to access the env vars from a component's script section (/src/components/Comp.vue).

This is how to access environment variables in cloudflare pages (using functions)
Use the context.env.[MY_ENV_VAR] to access the environment variable inside the js/ts file in functions folder

context.env.[MY_ENV_VAR]

Example:
Inside functions folder at the project root directory functions/env.js:
export async function onRequest(context) {
  const KEY = context.env.MY_KEY;

  return new Response(KEY)
}

visit https://[myproject_name].pages.dev/env to get a response with the KEY variable
This is the only way i know to access the environment variables,
if you want to access it in your code base i suggest executing whatever you want with the env variable (like making an api request) and then fetching the response from the api endpoint.
